# How to fetch Div content and appear corrent in html div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I use ajax to fetch data from DB ( a string and html content). And data.stPrp string can appear successfully, but html content of data.stPrc can't appear.

I have tested data.stPrc with alert(), and it can show the right content.

```
 alert(data.stPrc);
```

Here is my jsc code:

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType:'json',
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_ajax_csc.php",
        data:{stNum:stNum},
        success:function(data) 
        {
         $('#dlgPrpsr').text(data.stPrp);
         $('#timeTagDiv').html(data.stPrc);
         //alert(data.stPrc);
        }
    });
```

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="timeTag" id="timeTagDiv"></div>
```

Here is get_ajax_csc.php code:

```
 $sql="select customerAgent,process from IDC WHERE id='".$q."';
 $sel = $conn->query($sql); 
 $arr = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $tmpArr = array(
            'stPrp'=>$arr['customerAgent'],
            'stPrc'=>$arr['process'],
            );

 echo json_encode($tmpArr);
```

Here is process content in DB:

```
 <span class="dlgDate" id="firDlgDate">2017-09-12</span><br>
```

I have tried  $('#timeTagDiv').innerHTML(data.stPrc); and $('#timeTagDiv').text(data.stPrc); But they both are not working.

I suppose dataType:'json' influence the ajax return, I have no idea about it.

Comment: check the network tab in chrome dev tools to monitor the ajax call and check what it's returning.

Comment: did you getting any error in console ?

Comment: try `console.log(data);` in success function, look in console if data contains right data

Comment: Please error log `$arr['process']` and check what is the value of this variable

Comment: show class definitiion for class `timeTag`

Comment: "I suppose dataType:'json' inflences the ajax return" -- If so, try with `dataType:'text'` OR `dataType:'html'`